# Set multiple values in SQL ***make my job easier***

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-value

I use the following SQL query in work which works fine, however sometimes I need to update 1000+ values, and doing so one at a time is a laborious process, is there a way to be able to input multiple values at once, in this instance I have names of products and I need to set a name and section to them? Thanks in advance

```
use [Product.Extract] 
Begin TRANSACTION

Declare @name as varchar(255)
Declare @year as int
Declare @sectionid as int
-- Set variables
set @name = '225mm insulated efe'
set @year = 2021
set @sectionid = 1
--see original values
SELECT *
FROM Normalisation.productmap
where term = @name
-- Insert values
INSERT INTO Normalisation.productmap(name, year, sectionid)
VALUES(@name,
@year,
@sectionid)
```

Comment: Where do the values come from?

Comment: why don't you make script to automate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single `insert` statement with multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO Normalisation.productmap (name, year, sectionid)
    VALUES ('name1', 2020, 1),
           ('name1', 2020, 2),
           ('name1', 2020, 3),
           . . . ;
```

If the values come from a table, you can use an `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO Normalisation.productmap (name, year, sectionid)
    SELECT name, year, sectionid
    FROM temp_table;
```

If the values come from an external file, then you can use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).

Comment: Brilliant this works thank you, i work in sales and do not have an IT brain, I was given this task once a month to take some of the work from our busy data analysts